# jQuery check the right checkbox inside a TD

Tags: jquery, checkbox

You can se my problem here http://jsfiddle.net/eWh5F/76/ ()
what i want is to click on the TD and the checkbox should be checked/unchecked works fine for checkbox inside a TD but when I have a table inside a TD and TD inside that, any solution to that?
I have tried stuff like this below but whit no luck

```
$("td").click(function(e) {
var checkbox = $(':checkbox', $(this).parent()).get(0);
var checked = checkbox.checked;
if (checked == false) checkbox.checked = true;
else checkbox.checked = false;});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `prop` method:

```
$("td").click(function(e) {
    $('> input[type=checkbox]', this).prop('checked', function(i, checked){
       return !checked
    })
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jdy3d/

Note that `:checkbox` selector is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks!! Works exactly as I wanted :)

Comment: In this example, clicking the checkbox itself doesn't work.

Comment: @undefined. That's great. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `e.stopPropagation();`

```
$("td").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var checkbox = $('input[type="checkbox"]', $(this).closest('td')).get(0);
    var checked = checkbox.checked;
    if (checked == false) checkbox.checked = true;
    else checkbox.checked = false;
});​
```

`:checked` is **deprecated** use `input[type="checkbox"]` instead

Also use `$(this).closest('td')`  instead of `$(this).parent()`

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/eWh5F/77/)